# MongoDB : not able to get the field 'name' which has the max value in the two similar sub-documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a `test` collection:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5exxxxxx03"),
    "username" : "abc",
    "col1" : [
        {
            "colId" : 1
            "col2" : [
                {
                    "name" : "a",
                    "value" : 10
                },
                {
                    "name" : "b",
                    "value" : 20
                },
                {
                   "name" : "c",
                   "value" : 30
                }
            ],
            "col3" : [
                {
                    "name" : "d",
                    "value" : 15
                },
                {
                    "name" : "e",
                    "value" : 25
                },
                {
                    "name" : "f",
                    "value" : 35
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

`col1` has the list of sub-documents `col2` and `col3`, which are similar, but convey different meanings. These two sub-documents are having `name` and `value` as fields.

Now, I need to find the max `value` from `col2` or `col3` and its corresponding `name`.

I tried the below query:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$col1'},
    {$unwind: '$col1.col2'},
    {$unwind: '$col1.col3'},
    {$group:
        {_id: '$col1.colId',
        maxCol2: {$max: '$col1.col2.value'},
        maxCol3: {$max: '$col1.col3.value'}}},
    {$project:
        {maxValue: {$max: ['$maxCol2', '$maxCol3']},
        name: {$cond: [
            {$eq: ['$maxValue', '$maxCol2']},
            '$col1.col2.name',
            '$col1.col3.name']}}}]).pretty()
```

But, it resulted in the following, without `name` field in it:

```js
{ "_id" : 1, "maxValue" : 35 }
```

So, just to check, weather my condition is correct or not, tried the following query (`$col1.col2.name` and `$col1.col3.name` replaced with `111` and `222` strings):

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$col1'},
    {$unwind: '$col1.col2'},
    {$unwind: '$col1.col3'},
    {$group:
        {_id: '$col1.colId',
        maxCol2: {$max: '$col1.col2.value'},
        maxCol3: {$max: '$col1.col3.value'}}},
    {$project:
        {maxValue: {$max: ['$maxCol2', '$maxCol3']},
        name: {$cond: [
            {$eq: ['$maxValue', '$maxCol2']},
            '111',
            '222']}}}]).pretty()
```

Which gives me the expected output:

```js
{ "_id" : 1, "maxValue" : 35, "name" : "222" }
```

Could any one guide me why I am not getting the correct answer and how should I query this to get the correct output?

The correct out should be:

```js
{ "_id" : 1, "maxValue" : 35, "name" : "f" }
```

P.S. - I'm a beginner.

Comment: You could try something like $addFields to perform conditional mapping and remove conditionals from $project. Also,  if you aren't on the latest server release, try upgrading.

Comment: @ngShavil.py : What if you've multiple objects in `col1` array ? With `"colId" : 1`, `"colId" : 2` & `"colId" : 3`... Do you want to get greatest for each individual object inside `col1` or get greatest for all  `"colId" : 1`, `"colId" : 2` & `"colId" : 3`  combined ?

Comment: @whoami, I want to get the greatest for each individual objects inside `col1`.

Comment: @Oleg, thanks, I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

### Explanation

We need to add extra fields with `col2` and `col3` values. Once we calculate max value, we retrieve name based on max value.

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$col1"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$col1.col2"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$col1.col3"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$col1.colId",
      maxCol2: {
        $max: "$col1.col2.value"
      },
      maxCol3: {
        $max: "$col1.col3.value"
      },
      col2: {
        $addToSet: "$col1.col2"
      },
      col3: {
        $addToSet: "$col1.col3"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      maxValue: {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $gt: [
                  "$maxCol2",
                  "$maxCol3"
                ]
              },
              "$col2",
              "$col3"
            ]
          },
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.value",
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $gt: [
                      "$maxCol2",
                      "$maxCol3"
                    ]
                  },
                  "$maxCol2",
                  "$maxCol3"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$maxValue"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      maxValue: "$maxValue.value",
      name: "$maxValue.name"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V-d1-O0WZBp) | [Merging `col2` / `col3`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5rv1xFC832w) | [Per document](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TfRpwwFQNl6)

Comment: Actually, your query gives the exact output, which matches my expected output. But, are any slight modifications, which can be done to my query to get the desired output?

Comment: @ngShravil.py check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V-d1-O0WZBp). It's how we need to tune your solution to get desired result

Comment: Would you want to update the answer with this query?

Comment: @ngShravil.py Done. Thanks

Comment: I slightly modified the query, as `maxValue` and `name` fields were interchanged.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "col1": {
      "$max": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$col1",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$this.col2",
              "$$value",
              "$$this.col3"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2-JP5YDUcC_)

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I was looking for something similar to like my query. PS - I am a beginner.

Comment: can you break and explain each stage seperately ? Right now its too verbose

Comment: @KunalMukherjee `$reduce` used to flatten the nested arrays. `$max` to get the maximum value from the flattened array. You can check one by one by removing the operators from the query.